# C# countdown after opening box in the Unity game engine

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I need to access the PC or Android system time at opening a box and save it, then start counting down 5 minutes from that time. When 5 minutes pass, re-enable the button to open the box. I've tried many approaches but all lead to a dead end.

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button boxButton;
    long previousOpenedBox;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!boxButton.IsInteractable())
        {
            long diff = (DateTime.Now.Ticks - previousOpenedBox);
            //start counting down the time to re-enable the button.
        }
    }

    public void BoxClicked()
    {
        long previousOpenedBox = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        boxButton.interactable = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see at least one of the approaches you used?

Comment: I tried creating a timer, counting down with Time.deltaTime, unfortunately it counts down while the player is in the game. 

I tried the same scenario, but saving the result in the playerprefs, yet it saves the outcome on exit and starts counting again as soon as the player opens the game...

I tried getting the time using DateTime.Now and adding 5 minutes to it, then re-enable the button to open the box, but I get all sorts of errors this way.

If you need a code to be pasted most of it is not available anymore, but I can try to re-create it if it's going to be of help!

Comment: Instead of describing what your code does, can't you just copy-paste the relevant parts of it here?

Comment: I recreated some parts of my last script and posted it as an answer to the question

Comment: Oooops, you should edit your answer instead, this will make things confusing... anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you are implementing your opening logics when you update the box, you should put them in the `BoxClicked` method instead. This minimal example shows how to deal with a blocking delay and should point you to the right path.

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    private DateTime m_LastOpening;
    public Button m_BoxButton;

    public void BoxClicked()
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

        // 5 minutes elapsed, you can open the box
        if ((now - m_LastOpening).TotalMinutes > 5)
        {
            m_LastOpening = now;
            m_BoxButton.interactable = false;
        }
        else // otherwise you have to wait
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try out what you suggested as soon as I can! I guess TotalMinutes, Miliseconds etc. and the TimeSpan is really difficult for me to understand, I guess I need to study harder. After I try to implement it I will come back here to post my results. Thank you again!

Comment: It's not very difficult but actually the code is kinda simple. When the box is opened, you save the current time somewhere in a class variable. When you try to open it again, you see the difference, in minutes, between the current time and the last opening time. If that's greater than 5, you allow the box to be opened.

Comment: I tested it out and with some modification and fiddling around I made it fit into my project. Thanks!